# yii2 gii CRUD Generator error - Class 'Message' does not exist or has syntax error

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I'm creating a basic text only private messaging system for a website using yii2 advanced.

I'm using the gii model and CRUD generators but have encountered a problem with the CRUD generation after I have created the model class. I'm wondering whether it might be an issue with the foreign keys on the message table which have a one to many relationship with the users table (i.e. one user can have many messages).

When I attempt to run the CRUD generator with-
Model Class- Message
Search Model Class - frontend\models\search\MessageSearch
Controller Class - frontend\controllers\MessageController

I receive the following **error**-

> Class 'Message' does not exist or has syntax error.

The Message class definitely exists and 
the syntax is
 correct according to my IDE.

Any ideas what might be causing the error?

The generated message class is as follows -

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

/**
* This is the model class for table "message".
*
* @property integer $id
* @property string $title
* @property string $message
* @property integer $from_id
* @property integer $to_id
* @property integer $from_viewed
* @property integer $to_viewed
* @property integer $from_deleted
* @property integer $to_deleted
* @property string $from_vdate
* @property string $to_vdate
* @property string $from_ddate
* @property string $to_ddate
* @property string $created
*
* @property User $to
* @property User $from
*/
class Message extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'message';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['message', 'from_id', 'to_id', 'created'], 'required'],
        [['message'], 'string'],
        [['from_id', 'to_id', 'from_viewed', 'to_viewed', 'from_deleted', 'to_deleted'], 'integer'],
        [['from_vdate', 'to_vdate', 'from_ddate', 'to_ddate', 'created'], 'safe'],
        [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'message' => 'Message',
        'from_id' => 'From ID',
        'to_id' => 'To ID',
        'from_viewed' => 'From Viewed',
        'to_viewed' => 'To Viewed',
        'from_deleted' => 'From Deleted',
        'to_deleted' => 'To Deleted',
        'from_vdate' => 'From Vdate',
        'to_vdate' => 'To Vdate',
        'from_ddate' => 'From Ddate',
        'to_ddate' => 'To Ddate',
        'created' => 'Created',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getTo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'to_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getFrom()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'from_id']);
}
}
```

The table sql is -

```
--
```

### -- Table structure for table `message`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_viewed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_viewed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `from_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `from_vdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_vdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_ddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_ddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from_id` (`from_id`),
  KEY `to_id` (`to_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--

### -- Constraints for table `message`

ALTER TABLE `message`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `message_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`to_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `message_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`from_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);

Comment: What is frontend, in `namespace frontend\models;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that message you're getting, syntax error refers to an error in the class definition you're providing for gii. So gii is unable to find your model using `Message` as definition.

It should be `frontend\models\Message`.

Comment: Thanks- this was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into this [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3323).Your Model namespace may be the villain.

Try changing your Model namespace to

```
use app/models/Message
```

And I don't think the foreign keys has anything to do with your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the issue in my case.