# Gii: Class does not exist or has syntax error

Tags: php, model, yii2, crud, gii

I am trying to generate `CRUD` in `yii2` using `Gii`. I have created a model class using `Gii` and it is created successfully. But When I try to create `CRUD`, it gives the following error:

```
Class 'app\models\UserRoles' does not exist or has syntax error.
```

Here is the screen shot of what I am filling the form with and error:
[image] 
The class `UserRoles` exists and there is certainly no syntax error. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180534/yii2-gii-crud-generator-error-class-message-does-not-exist-or-has-syntax-err)
and it doesn't work either. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: first create model and try

Comment: I have created the model and it is created successfully as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because the class i gii can't revolve properly the  app\models\YourClassName (i have experienced  because create most of models in common\models  for share the models between frontend and backend)

be sure  where you have save the models  (could be in backend\models)

then set the proper value in

Model Class eg:

```
 backend\models\YourClassName
```

or simply

```
 YourClassName
```

And do the same for Search Model Class too

In viewpath you should use a proper alias so if you are in frontent

```
  @frontend\views\your-model-name
```

or (in some case)  you can set the abolute path to the directory you need

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the model is created in `frontend` and I am trying to create the `CRUD` in `frontend` as well. Still gives the error.

Comment: Have you tried to set   frontend\models\YourClassName   in the Model class field ?

Comment: Yes I did and it gave the exception first in the view path and then I tried it without `@` and it created but in the `web\app\` directory.

Comment: If i understand right  the message Class 'app\models\UserRoles' does not exist or has syntax error.  don't appear but you have a new error on the view path ?   please confirm

Comment: When I tried `frontend\models\UserRoles`, it did not give any error like `Class 'app\models\UserRoles' does not exist or has syntax error.` but gave error in view path. and then I removed the '@' from view path and it created the CRUD. But it created the views in `web\app\userroles` directory. I copied the folder and moved it to the desired location and it is working now.

Comment: I have update the answer  with a suggestion  for viewpath too

Comment: Thanks for your help! Got it now!

Comment: @Saani  well if my answer  is right please mark it as accepted .. otherwise  .. let me know if there are problems

Answer (score 1):

On the Model geneneration page change the namespace to the appropriate application. ie, change from app\models to either backend\models or frontend\models.

[change the namespace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VZ9b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check namaspace of your model class.
add Model class

```
app\models\YourClassName
```

add controller class

```
backend\controllers\Controller
```

view path

```
@backend/views/foldername
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to create crud in console with the following command:

```
php yii gii/crud --controllerClass=app\controllers\PostController --modelClass=app\models\Post
```

and get the same error. Finally, I run it successfully in this way:

```
php yii gii/crud --controllerClass=app\\controllers\\PostController --modelClass=app\\models\\Post
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's Showing that your Model class does not exist in the Model folder so First Create Model By gii -> Model Generator**

> 1. Select Table Name (drop-down list will generate Automatically).
> 2. Enter Model Class Name.
> 3. Click on Preview -> generate